# Cloning a div in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
      <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-0"></div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" ng-value="result" class="form-control" id="barcodeId1" placeholder="Barcode" ng-model="formData.barcode">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="displayProductDetails(this.formData.barcode)">Go!</button>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-bottom: 6px;">
                      <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: .75;">Name </label>
                      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="formData.name" ng-readonly="checked">
                  </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-bottom: 6px;">
                      <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: .75;">Mrp </label>
                      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="formData.mrp" ng-readonly="checked">
                  </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="radio"  name="reduction" value="Amount" ng-model="formData.amount">
                        Reduction Amount
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="formData.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                       <input type="radio" name="reduction" value="percentage" ng-model="percentage">
                        Reduction Percentage
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                          <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="formData.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
                      </label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And Controller Code

```
        scope.addMoreFields = function(event) {
            var div = document.getElementById('clonedInput1');
            scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
            var clone = div.cloneNode(true, true);
            console.log(clone);
            clone.id = "clonedInput" + scope.counter;
            var parentElement = angular.element(
                document.querySelector('.test'));
            var compiledElement = compile(clone)(scope);
            compiledElement.find('input').val('');
            parentElement.append(clone);
            var input = document.getElementById('clonedInput' + scope.counter).getElementsByTagName('input');
            console.log(input[0]);
            input[0].id = "barcodeId" + scope.counter;
        }
```

On click on addMore button, Control comes to addMoreFields .

I am getting the id of a div which to be cloned and changing its id and id of an input tag(so that each div will have a different id) and appending to parent.

Problem is while cloning data from textbox(barcode) also getting cloned.

Which shouldn't be.

Please Help me to solve the issue.

Comment: please add your question details and format your code

Comment: This may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367115/clone-elements-in-angularjs

Comment: @SantoshShinde i have edited my question.can you please check. And the code for controller is already uploaded.

Comment: @RAN can you tell me without using array? I have tried the same approach and faced different problems.Thank you

Comment: please check here http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/r23Sn/ , its may be help you